# LinkedIn Share Url not accepting french contents in IE 11

Tags: javascript, linkedin-api

I am using the below javascript code to open the LinkedIn url with some french content.

```
var link = 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + url + '&title=' + title + '&summary=' + summary + '&source=testing';
window.open(link, 'share_it', 'width=520,height=570');
```

But its working fine in chrome with below french contents but not working in IE 11. Its giving the 404 bad request error.

```
http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=http://testing/&title=PageTitle&summary=énergétique&source=testing
```

**EDIT:**

I have tried with `encodeURI` it opening the window but after logged in the summary is not getting displayed the title only getting displayed. What to do on this one.
[image]

Can anyone tell me what i have done wrong.?

Answer (score 1):

I just tried to use it on IE10. The issue is because of the characters in the french language that you must encode. To solve the issue simply use encodeURI() function and you won't get the Bad Request error.

```
var link = 'http://www.linkedin.com/shareArticle?mini=true&url=' + url + '&title=' + title + '&summary=' + summary + '&source=testing';
link = encodeURI(link);
window.open(link, 'share_it', 'width=520,height=570');
```

I tested it, and it was working fine for me on IE10 as well.

Comment: I have tried with encodeURI, but still getting issue. Please see my EDITS.